# A problem with limit of Definite Integral

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

$$\int_0^1 \frac{\sqrt{x}}{1+\sqrt[3]{x}}dx$$

I Know I should use this substitution: $x=t^6$, $dx=6t^5dt$ integral

$$\int_{{x_1}=0}^{{x_2}=1} \frac{\sqrt{x}}{1+\sqrt[3]{x}}dx=\int_{t_1}^{t_2} \frac{t^3(6t^5dt)}{1+t^2}$$

And also I can solve This integral

But I have problem with limits ( $t_1$,$t_2$) : $x_1=0$ so ${t_1}^6=0$ and $t_1=0$ and for $x_2=1$ so ${t_2}^6=1$ and $t_2=+1 $ and $t_2=-1 $

here I have problem whcich one Shluld I use as integral limit $t_2=+1 $ or  $t_2=-1 $ and Why?

Comment: This substitution typically refers to taking $t=\sqrt[6]{x}$ where the positive square root is taken. You can take the negative square root if you like but then $t^5=-\sqrt[6]{x^5}$ so you would get the same integral anyway.

Comment: Thanks I understand first part but what about $t^5=-\sqrt[6]{x^5}$ can you explain more?

Comment: My only point is that you can choose any one of the six complex roots and the integral will result in the same value. For example, when you take the negative square root, the substitution $u=-t$ will transform the integral into the one with the positive square root.

Comment: Oh, True got it

Answer (score 1):

> But I have problem with limits ( $t_1$,$t_2$) : $x_1=0$ so ${t_1}^6=0$ and $t_1=0$ and for $x_2=1$ so ${t_2}^6=1$ and $t_2=+1 $ and $t_2=-1 $
>
> here I have problem whcich one Shluld I use as integral limit $t_2=+1 $ or  $t_2=-1 $ and Why?

It doesn't matter if you choose $t_2=+1$ or $t_2=-1$, but I suspect that it is more natural to take the positive root. If $t_2=-1$ then

$$I= \int_{t_1}^{t_2} \frac{t^3(6t^5dt)}{1+t^2}=6 \int_{0}^{-1} -\frac{t^8}{1+t^2} dt$$

which by the substitution $u=-t$ is the same as the integral with $t_2=+1$

$$I=6 \int_{0}^{-1} -\frac{t^8}{1+t^2} dt=6 \int_{0}^{1} \frac{u^8}{1+u^2} du$$

as $t$ is replaced by $u$.

Answer (score 0):

$$I= 6 \int_{0}^{1} \frac{t^8}{1+t^2} dt= \int_{0}^{1} \left [t^6-t^4+t^2-1+\frac{1}{1+t^2} \right] dt$$ $$=6 [1/7-1/5+1/3-1 -\pi/4] = 6\left( \frac{\pi}{4}-\frac{76}{105}\right).$$